# Django -> Cannot resolve keyword error, but field is in Choices in traceback

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

Migrate to new Django and I receive this error. My models:

```
class TourRoute(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, verbose_name=_(u'tour'), db_index=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=_(u'country'), 
                                db_index=True)

class Tour(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(TourCategory, verbose_name=_(u'tour type'), 
                             null=True, blank=True)
    kind = models.ForeignKey(TourKind, verbose_name=_(u'tour kind'), null=True, 
                             blank=True, default=1)
    tour_class = models.ForeignKey(TourClass, verbose_name=_(u'class'), 
                             null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(TourType, verbose_name=_(u'tour type'), 
                             null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

In the views.py:

```
country_tours = Tour.objects.filter(tourroute__country__link=country.link)
```

In traceback django see this field ([iraceback image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XyBP.jpg)):
Cannot resolve keyword 'tourroute' into field. Choices are: accommodation_note, ... tourroute, ...

I try:

- adding related_name (tourroute changed in both traceback places to related_name value)
- drop all tables and creating new database on MySQL/PostgreSQL
- change replace my django (work in another project on the same server without this bug)

Comment: The traceback says the error is on line 153 of your template. Please show that part of your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error found - one of apps overly imports in django

Thanks for the help!

UPD: this stings in old app version are the reason this bug:

`options.Options._get_field = options.Options.get_field.im_func
 setattr(options.Options, 'get_field', get_field)`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a `_set` missing, should be:

```
country_tours = Tour.objects.filter(tourroute_set__country__link=country.link)
```

Or better, add a related name to the Model, to make it more readable

```
class TourRoute(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, verbose_name=_(u'tour'), 
                             db_index=True, related_name='routes')
```

So you can do

```
country_tours = Tour.objects.filter(routes__country__link=country.link)
```

Comment: before migration to new django this code have worked

Comment: I already try this - no result ( see higher: "adding related_name (tourroute changed in both traceback places to related_name value)" ).
Аdding "_set" not work too.

In this case my treysbek would not be so strange (tourroute is in choices)